# access subquery return value in union to other table postgres

Tags: postgresql

Given the following query:

```
select parent_id from (
    select parent_id, (most_recent_sit(date, child_id, key)).*
    from links
    where child_id = ANY(source_ids)
    group by parent_id
) as subquery
union select * from link_traversal(
    array(select parent_id from subquery),
);
```

Postgres throws the following error for the link_traversal function call:

```
relation "subquery" does not exist
```

link_traversal() and most_recent_sit() are custom functions I've created. I'd like to use the two functions and union the results together, where I reference the results of most_recent_sit() as the input for link_traversal().

Is it possible to reference a subquery select like so in a subsequent function call?

Comment: Look into common table expressions. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html

Comment: @VynlJunkie I'm unable to use CTE clause as it destroys the performance of the query, and am looking for an alternative. I've edited the question to include that information.